# Jquery Twitter search api - no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, search, twitter

I'm  using this [code](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) to query/search twitter.

On occasion my query will have no results. I want to display a line of text if the query has no results. A link to my page is [here.](http://www.hostelcities.com/dev/twitter/tweet/sunday.php)

I tried using jQuery :empty but it didn't work.

I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Brendon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the ninth example in your link has an example of how to handle a query with no results.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $("#empty").tweet({
          avatar_size: 32,
          count: 4,
          query: rnd,
          loading_text: "searching twitter..."
        }).bind("empty", function() { $(this).append("No matching tweets found"); });
      });
```

In your specific example you would do:

```
$(".sunday").tweet({
          avatar_size: 48,
          loading_text: "searching twitter...",
          query: "#sunday  from:Runs4Coffee OR from:mariaCBS13 OR from:Da_BEvans OR from:benhemmen OR from:brittany_franco OR from:BellaCMarlyn OR from:carlynveenkant OR from:HannibalsHood OR from:DirtCheapChickn OR from:RealKenyelAli OR from:RyeBeezy OR from:JaelynnDaSinger OR from:magichat OR from:Arabnblack OR from:statweestics OR from:mikegamboa04 OR from:Barnettrainer OR from:lahinke OR from:ParamountUK OR from:ryssaroo OR from:thewalkinmyth"
        }).bind("empty", function() { $(this).append("No matching tweets found"); });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before line 221 of jquery.tweet.js:

```
var tweets = $.map(data.results || data, extract_template_data);
```

put something like

```
if(data.results.length===0){
    $('#elementToDisplayNoItemsText').html('No items found');
}
```